# Getting rid of "==" syntax error in android

Tags: java, android

The `elseif(v == button2)` line gives an error saying that "Syntax error on token '==', delete this token". I got the idea of using this from the topic "Variable OnClick listener android" from this website. Can anyone please tell me how to use it?

Here is my code:

```
    View.OnClickListener yourListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if( v ==  button1){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Paracettamol")
                .setMessage("This medicine is generally used to cure Fever")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .show();}
            }
        elseif( v == button2){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        .setTitle("sertraline")
        .setMessage("This medicine is generally used to cure Head aches")
        .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
        .show();

        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        }  ; 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        }
```

The answer of the asked question mentioned above has the following code:

```
Button btn1, btn2;
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    // here you do normal things like assigning a
    // content view to the activity, initiate buttons, etc.

    // then you assign the same listener to both buttons
    btn1.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
}

// declare a OnClickListener that will execute different actions
// depending on the view that was clicked
View.OnClickListener yourListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void  onClick  (View  v){
        if( v == btn1 ){
            // do something 
        }
        elseif( v == btn1 ){
            // do another thing
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah...

Your code sample is a mess...

I've re-formatted it and correct errors. Now it should work.

```
View.OnClickListener yourListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == button1) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("Paracettamol")
                        .setMessage(
                                "This medicine is generally used to cure Fever")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
            } else if (v == button2) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("sertraline")
                        .setMessage(
                                "This medicine is generally used to cure Head aches")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
            }

        }
    };
```

Could you be more accurate asking question next time?

Comment: Oh! thanks for that. I would like to tell you that i am not a full grown software designer. i am only a first year IT student. i am just taking my first baby steps into IT.  thank you once again.

Answer (score 8):

You might missed space between else and if - "elseif( v == button2) "